# Best way to handle ajax request in Flux?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, flux

I'm thinking about Flux architecture of React and I want to identify the best way of handling Ajax requests. See the example of a comment box in below picture.

[image: React Flux example]

The overall architecture is clear, my concern is: should we really need a separate store for saving a view's private state such as Ajax request is failed?

Why we have stores is because data could be reused by different views. But should a network result also reused for other views besides the view originates the request?

Whether the ajax request success or fail is also a state of the view such as `setState({loading: true/false})`. And this state is not related with the data result of the request. The private loading state may be related with different network requests such as `post`, `refresh`, `delete` etc. I know some people suggests to provide a ErrorStore for this scenario. But if we don't develop stateless component I can't see any reason we only save network state in a separate store.

So in my project I use Promise:

```
actionCreators.postComment({...})
.then(res => this.setState({loading: false, error: null}))
.catch(err => this.setState({loading: false, error: err}));
```

The above code corresponds to the red part of the picture.

So my question is: is this approach reasonable? Or does Redux/Reflux have better ways? Thanks.

Comment: you may look at this article http://mjw56.github.io/handling-asynchronous-data-flow-in-flux/index.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't see an issue with storing the ajax request state in your store - you don't need a separate store just for that.  You can keep the state within your view store.

In your diagram, where you have the condition "Success?", it can dispatch a success or failure action and the store can save the fact that the request was a success (you may wish to have some sort of non-blocking UI which disappears when this is successful).

A request may fail because of a model validation error, not just a network failure.  In this case, it would be worthwhile storing these errors into the store, there's no harm in it.

One of the benefits of the Flux architecture is that there's single, defined flow of data, however in your diagram the flow of data is conditional depending on the success of ajax requests.  If you keep request states within your store, sent via dispatches, then you will maintain that single flow of data.